# plugin_host has exited unexpectedly

Tags: sublimetext3

I get this error on startup and what I've also noticed is when I try to use the shortcut for the tags, for example `div` and a `tab` key, it doesn't work. I have both codeIntel and Emmet installed, which one is responsible for this feature? I also deleted PyV8 so it's not the error source. Here's the log:

```
launching: /C/Program Files (x86)/Sublime Text 3/plugin_host.exe
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
loaded 837 snippets
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_file_settings
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin Emmet.emmet-plugin
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
reloading plugin SublimeCodeIntel.SublimeCodeIntel
plugins loaded
PyV8: Creating new thread
Emmet: Creating thread
Emmet: Loading https://api.github.com/repos/emmetio/pyv8-binaries/contents
error: plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue with following steps:

- Restart sublime
- Go to **Preferences | Package Control | Remove Package**
- Remove SublimeCodeIntel
- Restart

or, you can try to set `"ignored_packages":"SublimeCodeIntel"` in **Preferences | Settings - User**

May help.

Comment: Or just delete the folder .config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeCodeIntel

Answer (score -1):

I just by ST plug-in, first `sublimeCodeIntel`, then install a new plugin, each will try the front are working to find the problem, finally installed some necessary, is that all right now.